# Grunt - output 2 versions of web app

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm learning Grunt and trying to sort out how I can create 2 versions of the same application. The difference between the two are configuration settings.

Ideally, I would like the process to output 2 versions. One with a boolean in one of the .js files set to false, the other left to true. I would also need to concat and minify then file.

Is there a recommended way to do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify 2 configurations in your `grunt.initConfig`

```
grunt.initConfig({
    myTask: {
        version1: { ... }
        version2: { ... }
    }
})
```

And then register your default task to run each of these versions

```
grunt.task.registerTask("default", ["myTask:version1", "myTask:version2"])
```

Or just some other task name, `myTaskAllVersions` instead of `default`

You could use this versioning to flip your .js boolean, per version 1 or 2.

A similar approach could be taken to minifying and concatting the files afterwards, i.e.

```
grunt.initConfig({
    minify: {
        version1: { ... }
        version2: { ... }
    }
})
```

and

```
grunt.task.registerTask("default", ["myTask:version1", "minify:version1"])
```

Comment: badsyntax's answer also works, but I'm going to go this route, it is more suitable for my scenario. Thanks Stephen

Answer (score 0):

You could do all of this with the [uglifyjs grunt task](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify).

Here's an example of the config for your Gruntfile:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  uglify: {
    app1: {
      files: {
        'dist/app1.min.js': [
          'src/app1.js',
          'src/common.js'
        ]
      }
    },
    app2: {
      files: {
        'dist/app2.min.js': [
          'src/app2.js',
          'src/common.js'
        ]
      }
    }
  }
});
```